# how to solve import type error of RNFetchBlobNative

Tags: pdf, view

Failed to compile
/var/www/html/PDFdemo/node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/index.js 12:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   AppState,
| } from 'react-native'

> import type {
>   |   RNFetchBlobNative,
>   |   RNFetchBlobConfig,
>   This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.